# Problemas con Serializacion aplicacion Cliente-Servidor

Tags: java

Tengo una aplicacion cliente-servidor que tiene que escribir el objeto Jugador.Cuando corro la app en local funciona sin problemas pero cuando el cliente lo corro en una maquina virtual y el servidor en la local me lanza la excepcion ClassNotFoundException con el siguiente mensaje:"javax.swing.JComponent;local class incompatible:stream classdesc serialVersionUID=3742318830738515599,local class serialVersionUID=4588530037560142483"

codigo:

```
`public Jugador obtenerJugador(Socket socket,Jugador jugador) {
    ObjectInputStream lector = null;
    try {
    lector=new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    jugador= (Jugador) lector.readObject();
    jugador.setTurno(0);}
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Clase no encontrada");
    e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (IOException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error al obtener el objeto"+e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();}
```

La clase Jugador tiene un tablero que hereda de JPanel,es el unico componente swing que tiene la clase,jugador y la excepcion que se lanza habla de un JComponent,supongo que ese es el problema pero no se como arreglarlo.Todas las clases del proyecto implementan Serializable

Answer (score 1):

Debes definir la propiedad `serialVersionUID` en la clase:

```
class MyClass implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6529685098267757690L;
```

**¿Qué es serialVersionUID?**

Es un número de versión que posee cada clase Serializable, el cual es usado en la deserialización para verificar que el emisor y el receptor de un objeto serializado mantienen una compatibilidad en lo que a serialización se refiere con respecto a la clases que tienen cargadas (el emisor y el receptor).

**¿Qué pasa si no se declara un serialVersionUID?**

El proceso de serialización asocia cada clase serializable a un serialVersionUID. Si la clase no especifica un serialVersionUID el proceso de serializacion  calculará un serialVersionUID por defecto, basandose en varios aspectos de la clase. Es muy recomendable que se declare un serialVersionUID en las clases serializables, ya que el calculo del serialVersoinUID es muy sensible a detalles de la clase, los cuales pueden variar entre compiladores, es decir, si trabajamos serializando/deserializando objetos y trabajamos con distintos compiladores Java podemos llegar a obtener una InvalidClassException durante el proceso de deserialización debido a discrepancias entre los serialVersionUID calculados por cada compilador.

Comment: si amigo,todas mis clases tienen implementada la interfaz Serializable y con el serialVersionUID escrito,no se cual es el error.Puede ser que tenga distintos compiladores,pero el codigo lo corre,el problema es en la serializacion

Comment: Ok. El siguiente paso es verificar que en ambas máquinas esté instalado exactamente el mismo JRE.